# What are low pass and high side driver MOSFET?

Tags: mosfet, mosfet-driver

I am beginer in power electronics. I know that transistor are used either as amplifier or as a switch.
While reading about MOSFET , I found the term i.e. low side and high side driver.
So can anyone explain

1. What is the term mosfet **driver**?
2. What are high side and low side drivers and their difference?

Answer (score 1):

1. A mosfet driver is a circuit or device that drives the gate of a mosfet.  While the gate doesn’t draw DC current it has some capacitance and so needs a relatively high current driver to switch quickly.
2. High pass and low pass refer to filters that allow high and low frequencies through while stopping low and high frequencies respectively.  Don’t confuse this with high and low side drivers, which switch a power supply on either the positive (high) or negative (low) side.